# The Q of LC filter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, filter, dc-dc-converter

I've designed a full-bridge dc-dc converter and output filter is "L=8.3mH and C=20uF", max load is "61.3R". These values are giving me Q=3.(Calculated with "Rout / SQRT(L/C)")

Is Q=3 acceptable or not? If not, what to do here?

Sorry if I ask useless question, it's my first time dealing with output filter's Q.

Comment: Well, we can't tell you if your filter is good enough for your purpose! (We don't know that purpose.) What would you need help with to determine whether that is the case?

Comment: The filter resonant f is too small 390 Hz for a SMPS with such a large L. and with no load would become unstable with a much higher Q and too much stored energy and lag in response so the Series R must also be regulated to lower the Q with PFM and/or PWM

Comment: Filter is output LC filter of a full-bridge dc-dc converter. Since the Q is associated with phase slope, high Q is not good for stability so I'm suspicious about filter's stability because I don't know what is nominal Q range or if any damping is needed when Q=3 @MarcusMüller

Comment: Ah I see, you're worried what happens when you actually hit the resonance frequency(ies) of your filter!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thank you for information, I've calculated L for %5 current ripple and I'm not going to use it without load.

Comment: the entire specs are needed, V, I, f , DCR, losses  tolerances...in the question

Comment: The inductance value looks extremely high to me. What are the operating elements of this converter? (power, input voltage and switching frequency). Then, the \$Q\$ of the filter is what it is and if you design it to be the most possible efficient (low dc resistance and low ESR) then its \$Q\$ will naturally be high. What truly matters is that the selected crossover frequency \$f_c\$ be selected to be well above the resonant frequency so that the filter is sufficiently damped in closed-loop conditions. A plot of the closed-loop \$Z_{out}\$ will tell you if the compensation is acceptable.

Comment: @VerbalKint converter is: 48V input(40V-60V), 350V output full-bridge dc-dc converter, operated in 30kHz frequency, output power is 2kW. I calculated inductance for %5 output current ripple but this is not a must, I can increase it. Crossover frequency is selected as 5kHz.

Comment: I think you can increase the inductor ripple current. Considering the low-loss materials these days, it is not uncommon to design for 30-40% ripple. If you operate in current-mode control, there won't be peaking on the control-to-output transfer function beside the sub-harmonic poles. Peaking and the notion of \$Q\$ will be pertinent if you go for voltage-mode control only.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I have a PCB and it's designed for voltage mode control with type3 compensator. Does 30-40% voltage ripple acceptable for voltage mode control or should I go for lower like 20% because of voltage mode control?

Comment: The amount of ripple does not link with the control method and you can decrease your inductor value by keeping an eye on the circulating rms currents while doing this.